# Получение текста между тегами - bs4

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup, bs4

Задача заключается в получении текста между html тегами

```
<a href="/valyuty/GBP-RUB" title="GBP/RUB">GBP/RUB</a>
```

использовать .text не дает результатов, ибо bs4 не отображает этот текст между тегов. Соответственно, когда юзаю .text дает пустую строку.
Вот часть кода:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("table", class_="quote_list")
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    name = row.find("a")
    value = row.find("span")
    if name is None or value is None:
        continue
    print(name, value.text)
```

Вывод программы такой (таких строк больше, привел одну):

```
<a class="image_icon_chart" href="/valyuty/v-realnom-vremeni/GBP-RUB"></a> 82,7504
```

Нужно чтобы вывело содержимое между тегами. То есть name.text (что не работает).
Как видно из вывода программы, bs4 вообще не видит текст между тегами, хотя он там есть! value.text выводит нормально!

Comment: добавьте в вопрос минимальный, но полный пример кода, который демонстрирует проблему. [mcve]

Comment: Попробуйте .content

Comment: .content не работает, выдает None. Говорю же, bs4 не видит что находится между тегами вообще, то есть когда вывожу html вид "верхнего" тега тоже не показывает содержимое между тегами

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы найти текст в `<a>` элементе c помощью `BeautifulSoup` ([repl.it](https://repl.it/@zed1/beautifulsoup-find-text)):

```
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<a href="/valyuty/GBP-RUB" title="GBP/RUB">GBP/RUB</a>', 'html.parser')
>>> soup.a.text
'GBP/RUB'
```